# Polymorphic one-to-many relationship where "many" are of different subclasses

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, relationship

I have a `Player` class and each player owns X amount of `Character` instances:

```
class Player(Model):
    characters = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')

class Character(Model):
    owner = relationship('Player', back_populates='characters')
    owner_id = Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    level = Column(Integer, default=0)
```

But now I want to make `Character` a base class with `__abstract__` and only record its subclasses' instances into the database:

```
class Character(Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    owner = relationship('Player', back_populates='characters')
    owner_id = Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))
    level = Column(Integer, default=0)

    def use_special_ability(self, target):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Warrior(Character):
    def use_special_ability(self, target):
        bla_bla(target)

class Mage(Character):
    def use_special_ability(self, target):
        foo(self.level, bar=True)
```

It doesn't matter to me whether there's only one `character` table or if all character subclasses get their own tables (although the former is slightly preferred), as long as the Python side works "flawlessly", i.e. every player has **one** list of characters regardless of their types.

How would I change the relationship so that it works for multiple subclasses like this?

Comment: @NikhilRupanawar This is SQLAlchemy though, your link is Django

Comment: You should use [single table inheritance](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html#single-table-inheritance). You need to add a `type` column to distinguish between `Warrior` and `Mage` though.

Comment: I'm really not sure how that can be adjusted to my use case, I did read it through but I can't quite connect the pieces...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
class Player(Model):
    __tablename__ = "player"

    characters = relationship('Character', back_populates='owner')


class Character(Model):
    __tablename__ = "character"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Enum("warrior", "mage")), nullable=False)
    owner = relationship('Player', back_populates='characters')
    owner_id = Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id'))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_on": type,
    }

    ...


class Warrior(Character):
    __tablename__ = None

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "warrior",
    }

    ...


class Mage(Character):
    __tablename__ = None

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "mage",
    }

    ...
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know all the possible `Enum` options at the time of creating `Character` base class -- this is a plugin for CS:GO and the server operators themselves can create any arbitary number of subclasses which will then be added to the server

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen You can use a string column.

Comment: Uh, right, of course. Thanks, I'll give this a try first thing in the morning!

Comment: Is there any wya to automate this process, so I wouldn't need to redefine `__tablename__` and `__mapper_args__` everytime?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen You can omit `__tablename__` if you're using standard SQLAlchemy (some libraries will autogenerate `__tablename__` based on the name of the class). I only included it for clarity. You can use [`declared_attr`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declared_attr) for `__mapper_args__`. You'll find a very pertinent example on that page.

Comment: Awesome, everything seems to work. Thanks for all the help mate! :) @univerio